# Tool to monitor IE performance running JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer

Company I work for are one of the largest betting companies in Europe and the website has thousands of lines of JavaScript on all our pages.

Lately Internet Explorer versions earlier than version 9 are running painfully slow and I want to be able to monitor what parts of a page load (including scripts) that are slow. I know that IE are slower in general and has DOM API issues etc.

What I want to accomplish is a way to quickly identify slow parts and see if we can replace the code with IE specific code that will render with higher performance.

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [dynaTrace AJAX [sic] edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/Default.aspx) before and found it useful.

Answer (score 4):

IE9 has great profiling functionalities (F12).

Activate the development tools, click on the profiling tab and start profiling when you work with your app. Stop the profiling and you can see all the function calls, the time spent, etc.

Comment: he's looking for help with IE<9, so that doesn't really help.

Comment: Actually you can emule IE7 and IE8 behavious through IE9's dev tool menu.